# how do you merge cells from a Row into one cell in a LIST

Tags: arrays, join, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, textjoin

I am trying to merge 3 cells from 3 different sheets into one cell but in a LIST form on google SpreadSheets. I have tried;

```
Concat()
Concatenate()
```

But these only merge cells into an 1-D array. In other words, this is what I got;

```
'Sheet1!'A1={ Phil }, 'Sheet2!'A1={ Bill }, 'Sheet3!'A1={ Stan }
```

This is what I'd like;

```
              Phill
'Sheet4!'A1={ Bill }
              Stan
```

It seems simple but I am fairly new to this. Thank you guys for your time in advance!

Comment: share a copy of your sheet with exammple of desired result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

paste in **Sheet4!A1**:

```
=Sheet1!A1&CHAR(10)&Sheet2!A1&CHAR(10)&Sheet3!A1
```

or:

```
=JOIN(CHAR(10), Sheet1!A1, Sheet2!A1, Sheet3!A1)
```

if name is missing do:

```
=TEXTJOIN(CHAR(10), 1, Sheet1!A1, Sheet2!A1, Sheet3!A1)
```